# How to print a div's width-percentage in that particular offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div having a width of 300px. I want to run a loop through it which will check its width px by px (offset by offset) and print the key percentages in that exact position of the div (that offset's exact position). How can this be implemented using Javascript? If possible, Jquery is welcome.

For example, if the div is of 100px; then I will need to print 10 on the position of 10px inside the div, 20 on 20px and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Create child elements containing those numbers, and position them absolutely …

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/np3pc56x/1/

Comment: @CBroe Since I am learning Javascript, want to add those dynamically.

Comment: Great, then do that. And if you have any problems doing that, then give us a proper problem description, and show us relevant code. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @ChrisG You saved my day! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood **you need to receive The EXACT percentage offset of an element FROM THE PAGES OFFSET**, if so here you go :

```js
function PERCENT(){
      subj = '#nem';
      pageh =  window.innerHeight;
      pagew =  window.innerWidth;
      subjtop =  $(subj).offset().top;
      subjleft =  $(subj).offset().left;
  
    T = ( subjtop / pageh ) * 100;
       L = ( subjleft / pagew ) * 100;
            $(subj).html( 'T:'+T+' %<br> L: '+L+' %' );
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){PERCENT();})
    $(window).resize(function(){PERCENT()})
```

```css
#nem{
   position: absolute; top: 124px; left: 69px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='nem'></div>
```

now if you need this data to be updated simultaneously you can **set an interval** to update the data by time